# Find all objects in Matlab figure which have a callback

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

In my current figure I need to find all objects which have some callback set. More specifically, all objects which have a non-empty ButtonDownFcn.

I tried everything, e.g.  `findobj(gca, '-regexp', 'ButtonDownFcn', '\s+')`, but I get this error: `Warning: Regular expression comparison is not supported for the 'Callback' property: using ordinary comparison.`

The problem is that the objects have no tags or anything which would "define" them uniquely, except that they are all "clickable". Is there an easy way to do it? Using findobj or findall.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`findobj`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/findobj.html) does not support regular expression comparison for the `'ButtonDownFcn'` property, as the warning says. This probably happens because the contents of the property are not necessarily text (they can be function handles).

You can use a [`for`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/for.html) loop over all objects of the figure:

```
result = [];
hh = findobj(gcf);
for h = hh(:).'
    if ~isempty(get(h, 'ButtonDownFcn'))
        result = [result h];
    end
end
```

Or equivalently you can use [`arrayfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html):

```
hh = findobj(gcf);
ind = arrayfun(@(h) ~isempty(get(h, 'ButtonDownFcn')), hh);
result = hh(ind);
```

Comment: Thanks. That's what I already have. I was hoping for some "undocumented" feature of findobj (or allchild or findall or some other function).

Comment: @pisoir You should have specified what you already have, to avoid wasting time of potential answer writers. Also, undocumented features are dangerous because they might stop working in future Matlab versions

Comment: I had the for loop, but the arrayfun is a nice one.